# insulating a new room in garage

Tags: insulation

I have a 2 story garage with a loft running down the middle and leaving a lot of open space between the ground floor and roof. I'm making a temperature controlled room and the walls are built already. Im having a hard time figuring out what kind of insulation to lay on the ceiling, the walls will use blown in insulation. Can I just pack the ceiling with blown in stuff or do I need to find some other way to insulate the room and keep it warm/cold?

Comment: Is the new room the loft? Or is it the entire ground floor of the garage? Or part of the ground floor of the garage?

Comment: If there is space above the ceiling, it's entirely reasonable to blow in insulation. My attic isn't used for storage, so it has a layer of blow-in that was originally 3 feet deep. (It has compacted a bit over time and when I've had to do something up there.)